# If else In sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, if-statement

i am trying to run query within if else block.Like below In this query first i check for if database exist or not else i will execute another query to create it.But every time when i run this query it executing else block even if there database exist,what to do is syntax is wrong?

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'SampleDB')
    BEGIN
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN   
    CREATE DATABASE [SampleDB]  
    go
    use [SampleDB] 
    Go

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'autoclose', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'bulkcopy', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'trunc. log', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'torn page detection', N'true'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'read only', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'dbo use', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'single', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'autoshrink', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'ANSI null default', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'recursive triggers', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'ANSI nulls', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'concat null yields null', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'cursor close on commit', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'default to local cursor', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'quoted identifier', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'ANSI warnings', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'auto create statistics', N'true'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'auto update statistics', N'true'
    GO


    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BrandMaster] (
        [BrandId] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) CONSTRAINT [PK_BrandMaster] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
        [BrandName] [nvarchar] (50) NOT NULL ,
        [BrandStatus] [bit] NOT NULL ,
         )
    GO


    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[BrandMaster] ON
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[BrandMaster] OFF



    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BrandProductMaster] (
        [BrandProductId] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) CONSTRAINT [PK_BrandProductMaster] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
        [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL ,
        [BrandId] [int] NOT NULL ,
        [Units] [nvarchar] (15) NULL ,
        [Status] [bit] NOT NULL ,
         )
    GO


    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[BrandProductMaster] ON
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[BrandProductMaster] OFF




    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BrokerMaster] (
        [BrokerId] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) CONSTRAINT [PK_BrokerMaster] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
        [BrokerName] [nvarchar] (100) NOT NULL ,
        [BrokerPercentage] [float] NOT NULL ,
        [BrokerAddress] [nvarchar] (100) NULL ,
        [BrokerTelephoneNo] [bigint] NULL ,
        [BrokerMobileNo] [bigint] NULL ,
        [BrokerFaxNo] [bigint] NULL ,
        [BrokerEmailId] [nvarchar] (75) NULL ,
        [BrokerStatus] [bit] NOT NULL ,
    )
    GO

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[BrokerMaster] ON
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[BrokerMaster] ([BrokerId],[BrokerName],[BrokerPercentage],[BrokerAddress],[BrokerEmailId],[BrokerStatus])
        VALUES (1,'No Broker',0.0,'','',1)
    GO

    SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[BrokerMaster] OFF

    GO
END
```

After EDIT :

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'SampleDB')
    CREATE DATABASE [SampleDB]  
    go
    use [SampleDB] 
    Go

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'autoclose', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'bulkcopy', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'trunc. log', N'false'
    GO

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'torn page detection', N'true'
    GO
......
```

Comment: You could modify your script by using NOT EXISTS, that way you wouldn't have to use a redundant IF, BEGIN, END block.

Comment: tried NOT EXISTS but executing same thing,See the updated questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `GO` inside a `BEGIN`/`END` block. `GO`(*) is a command to your client tool to take all of the text back to the previous `GO` (or the start of the file) and ask SQL Server to execute it (it's called a batch). SQL Server compiles all of that text and then executes it. So it will see an incomplete structure:

```
IF
BEGIN
END
ELSE
BEGIN
```

With no `END` for that last `BEGIN`, so you'll always get an error. It never gets as far as actually trying to execute the code.

---

(*) Actually, it could be anything. But only a psychopath would alter their tool settings away from the default value of `GO`.

---

I would do this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'SampleDB')
BEGIN   
    CREATE DATABASE [SampleDB]  

    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'autoclose', N'false'
    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'bulkcopy', N'false'
    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'trunc. log', N'false'
    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'torn page detection', N'true'
    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'read only', N'false'
    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'dbo use', N'false'
    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'single', N'false'
    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'autoshrink', N'false'
    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'ANSI null default', N'false'
    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'recursive triggers', N'false'
    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'ANSI nulls', N'false'
    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'concat null yields null', N'false'
    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'cursor close on commit', N'false'
    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'default to local cursor', N'false'
    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'quoted identifier', N'false'
    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'ANSI warnings', N'false'
    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'auto create statistics', N'true'
    exec sp_dboption N'SampleDB', N'auto update statistics', N'true'
END
go
use SampleDB
go
if not exists (select * from sys.tables where name='BrandMaster')
begin
    exec sp_executesql N'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BrandMaster] (
        [BrandId] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) CONSTRAINT [PK_BrandMaster] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
        [BrandName] [nvarchar] (50) NOT NULL ,
        [BrandStatus] [bit] NOT NULL ,
         )'

    exec sp_executesql N'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BrandProductMaster] (
        [BrandProductId] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) CONSTRAINT [PK_BrandProductMaster] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
        [ProductId] [int] NOT NULL ,
        [BrandId] [int] NOT NULL ,
        [Units] [nvarchar] (15) NULL ,
        [Status] [bit] NOT NULL ,
         )'

    exec sp_executesql N'CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BrokerMaster] (
        [BrokerId] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) CONSTRAINT [PK_BrokerMaster] PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
        [BrokerName] [nvarchar] (100) NOT NULL ,
        [BrokerPercentage] [float] NOT NULL ,
        [BrokerAddress] [nvarchar] (100) NULL ,
        [BrokerTelephoneNo] [bigint] NULL ,
        [BrokerMobileNo] [bigint] NULL ,
        [BrokerFaxNo] [bigint] NULL ,
        [BrokerEmailId] [nvarchar] (75) NULL ,
        [BrokerStatus] [bit] NOT NULL ,
    )'
    exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO [dbo].[BrokerMaster] ([BrokerName],[BrokerPercentage],[BrokerAddress],[BrokerEmailId],[BrokerStatus])
        VALUES (''No Broker'',0.0,'''','''',1)'
END
```

Comment: what can be used instead of **go**?will it get execute if i remove go

Comment: @sharad - I've updated with a complete script. I don't muck about with identity insert since these are brand new tables, and the behaviour is *slightly* different (it will attempt to re-add the tables if the database existed but `BrandMaster` didn't)

Comment: @sharad - Oh, and I'd also look at switching away from `sp_dboption` and using [`ALTER DATBASE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174269(v=sql.90).aspx) or include the appropriate options in the initial `CREATE`. This is one of those cases where not only have MS warned about a future removal, it's already happened (`sp_dboption` is not available in SQL Server 2012)